# Cqlsh error on cassandra 2.0.1

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

We recently upgraded to cassandra 2.0.1 with cqlsh 4.0.1. I am seeing timeout errors/ broken pipe while using the cqlsh client. Please see error trace below. I have verified that the cluster is Up using nodetool and I am able to read/write using mapreduce. Please advice.

Thanks,
Prateek

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/cqlsh", line 897, in perform_statement_untraced
    self.cursor.execute(statement, decoder=decoder)
  File "./bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.0.zip/cql-1.4.0/cql/cursor.py", line 80, in execute
    response = self.get_response(prepared_q, cl)
  File "./bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.0.zip/cql-1.4.0/cql/thrifteries.py", line 77, in get_response
    return self.handle_cql_execution_errors(doquery, compressed_q, compress, cl)
  File "./bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.0.zip/cql-1.4.0/cql/thrifteries.py", line 96, in handle_cql_execution_errors
    return executor(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.0.zip/cql-1.4.0/cql/cassandra/Cassandra.py", line 1782, in execute_cql3_query
    self.send_execute_cql3_query(query, compression, consistency)
  File "./bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.0.zip/cql-1.4.0/cql/cassandra/Cassandra.py", line 1793, in send_execute_cql3_query
    self._oprot.trans.flush()
  File "./bin/../lib/thrift-python-internal-only-0.9.1.zip/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 292, in flush
    self.__trans.write(buf)
  File "./bin/../lib/thrift-python-internal-only-0.9.1.zip/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 128, in write
    plus = self.handle.send(buff)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: Are you restarting cassandra without then restarting cqlsh?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an open cqlsh session, it will always give you Errno 32 if the Cassandra instance that it connected to was stopped or even just restarted. You will have to restart cqlsh in order to re-establish a connection to the server.

If you see this problem without having stopped or restarted a Cassandra server, then please supply and additional details about conditions that lead up to this error.